# Is it possible to find (in an ordered table) multiple rows in sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, where-clause

If I have a table ordered by ID like so:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Key       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        Foo       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        Bar       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |        Test      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |        Test      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Is there a way to detect two rows that match a where clause in sequence?

For example, in the table above, I would like to see if any two rows in succession have a Key of 'test'.

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: You can do a self join.

Comment: A [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a specific server object that doesn't play into this question. I removed that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is a variation of Gaps-and-Islands

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Key] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Foo')
,(2,'Bar')
,(3,'Test')
,(4,'Test')

Select ID_R1 = min(ID)
      ,ID_R2 = max(ID)
      ,[Key]
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = ID-Row_Number() over(Partition By [Key] Order by ID) 
         From @YourTable
       ) A 
 Group By [Key],Grp
 Having count(*)>1
```

**Returns**

```
ID_R1   ID_R2   Key
3       4       Test
```

> **EDIT - Just in case the IDs are NOT Sequential**

```
Select ID_R1 = min(ID)
      ,ID_R2 = max(ID)
      ,[Key]
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = Row_Number() over(Order by ID)
                    -Row_Number() over(Partition By [Key] Order by ID) 
         From @YourTable
       ) A 
 Group By [key],Grp
 Having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEAD()` window function, as in:

```
with 
x as (
  select
    id, [key], 
    lead(id) over(order by id) as next_id,
    lead([key]) over(order by id) as next_key
  from my_table
)
select id, next_id from x where [key] = 'test' and next_key = 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function check the gap.

```
SELECT [Key]
FROM (
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY ID) grp
     FROM T 
)t1
GROUP BY [Key]
HAVING COUNT(grp) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self join as

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  [Key] VARCHAR(45)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'Foo'),
(2, 'Bar'),
(3, 'Test'),
(4, 'Test');

SELECT MIN(T1.ID) One,
       MAX(T2.ID) Two,
       T1.[Key] OnKey
FROM T T1 JOIN T T2
ON T1.[Key] = T2.[Key]
   AND
   T1.ID <> T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.[Key];
```

Or a `CROSS JOIN` as

```
SELECT MIN(T1.ID) One,
       MAX(T2.ID) Two,
       T1.[Key] OnKey
FROM T T1 CROSS JOIN T T2
WHERE T1.[Key] = T2.[Key]
      AND
      T1.ID <> T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.[Key]
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8dd5629971d7a47a4e13d9170d43634)**